# How can I disable a warning in XCode that is in an xib file

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I found a few answers for doing it in code files, but my warning is coming from interface builder, and it is silly.

**Attribute unavailable: Defines Presentation Context is not available prior to Xcode 4.2.**

I *am* using Xcode 4.2.  Why would I possibly care about this warning?  Lots of things don't work in Xcode 0.01.  This is day one of a new project and I don't want to spend the whole time violating the no-checking-in-with-warnings rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select xib file; in the Utilities pane (on the right), under File Inspector tab, find "Interface Builder Document" section; change the Development property to "Default Version (Interface Builder 4.2)".

Comment: And thar she blows.  "Development: Default Version (Xcode 4.1)" is set.  What an odd default.

Comment: @CBGraham Maybe it's because your project is in Xcode 4.1 format.